# ASP.NET code that saves .jpg files from stream does not save .gif files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stream, jpeg, gif

I'm getting the error `A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.`

The code below saves an image on my server when

```
imageURL="http://www.wijny.nl/imagestore/product/375/villamariaestateprivatebinsauvignonblancmarlboroughnewzealand10126029.jpg"
```

The code does NOT save any image when

```
imageURL="http://www.wijny.nl/imagestore/product/377/villamariasinglevineyardcha.gif"
```

The only difference I see is the format of the image source, .jpg files are stored correctly, .gif files are not. How can I make sure the code saves any type of image, whether, .png, .jpg or .gif?

```
Dim imgRequest As WebRequest
Dim imgResponse As WebResponse
Dim imgStream As Stream
imgRequest = WebRequest.Create(imageURL)

Dim localImageFilename as String = 'test.jpg'

Try
    imgResponse = imgRequest.GetResponse()
    imgStream = imgResponse.GetResponseStream()
Catch ex As Exception
    LogError("imgRequest.GetResponse", ex.Message)
End Try

imgRemoteImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgStream)
localImagePath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("photospath").ToString) + localImageFilename

ResizeAndSaveImage(1200, 1200, localImagePath, imgRemoteImage)

Private Function ResizeAndSaveImage(ByVal maxWidth As Integer, ByVal maxHeight As Integer, ByVal path As String, ByVal img As System.Drawing.Image) As Boolean
    Dim newWidth, newHeight As Integer
    Dim scaleFactor As Double
    Dim bResult As Boolean
    newWidth = img.Width
    newHeight = img.Height

    If img.Width > maxWidth Or img.Height > maxHeight Then
        If img.Width > maxWidth Then
            scaleFactor = maxWidth / img.Width
            newWidth = Math.Round(img.Width * scaleFactor, 0)
            newHeight = Math.Round(img.Height * scaleFactor, 0)
        End If
        If newHeight > maxHeight Then
            scaleFactor = maxHeight / newHeight
            newWidth = Math.Round(newWidth * scaleFactor, 0)
            newHeight = Math.Round(newHeight * scaleFactor, 0)
        End If
    End If

        Try
            Dim bMap As New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, img.PixelFormat)

            Dim gr As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bMap)
            gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            gr.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High

            Dim rectDestination As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
            gr.DrawImage(img, rectDestination, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            bMap.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 
            bMap.Dispose()

            bResult = True

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Return bResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change the `PixelFormat` parameter,

This works for `.gif` files: `bMap = New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)`

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to your function:

```
Private Function ResizeAndSaveImage(ByVal maxWidth As Integer, ByVal maxHeight As Integer, ByVal path As String, ByVal img As System.Drawing.Image, byval Extension as String) As Boolean ' where extension comes from your filename...it'll either be GIF, JPG, or PNG.
```

Then do something like this where you're saving the bitmap:

```
if Extension = "JPG" then
    bMap.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 
elseif Extension = "GIF" then
    bMap.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
else
    bMap.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) 
end if
```

You may also want to include a check to see if a valid extension is being passed, but that depends on what you're doing and whether or not you think it's necessary.

Comment: I tried that an now get: `A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.`